# How to read an odata url and save it as a json file using PowerShell script

Tags: json, powershell, odata, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

When I try to read this url using the below PowerShell command I'm not able to open the page

```
Start-Process "iexplore.exe" "https://sitename//odata/ScheduledJobs?$format=json&$expand=Application($select=Id,Name,AssetId;$expand=Asset($select=Id,Name)),JobType,JobInstances($filter=StartTime+eq+null;$orderby=NextRunTime+asc;$top=1),CompletedJobs($orderby=StartTime+desc;$top=1;$expand=State;$select=Id,StateId,StartTime,EndTime)&$top=20&$orderby=ScheduleStart&$filter=Enabled+eq+true&$count=true"

Get-Process | Out-File -filepath C:\Users\S.Papolu\Downloads\ScheduledJobs1.json
```

How to open that url in IE and download the json output?

Please help me on this, appreciate your help, please post the code

Comment: `Start-Process` starts a process and an instance of IE. It does not read that data on the page. You should use `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod` to do that. Once you get the data, pipe it to `ConvertTo-Json` before using `Out-File`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions here.  I think you answered the first one yourself.  How do I open a URL in Internet Explorer?  Your `start-process` statement does this.

The second question might be unrelated to the first:  How do I download the JSON to a file.

You can look at the `invoke-webrequest` cmdlet to download the content of a URL to a file.
You want something like

```
$uri = "https://sitename//odata/ScheduledJobs?`$format..."
iwr -Uri $uri -OutFile C:\Users\S.Papolu\Downloads\ScheduledJobs1.json -UseBasicParsing
```

Note the use of double quotes for the content of the url and the backtick before the $ in the content.  You need something like this to tell powershell to pass the $ through as a literal instead of trying to substitute a variable named FORMAT here.

If you need credentials to access `https://sitename` then you may be able to use the `certificate` or `certificatethumbprint` parameters if your site uses client access certificates, the `UseDefaultCredentials` parameter if your current credentials work on the site, or you may need to create a headers collection and with an Authorization header and pass in a valid token.

```
$headers=@{"Authorization"="Bearer Your_BearerTokenHere"}
iwr -Uri $uri -OutFile 'C:\Users\S.Papolu\Downloads\ScheduledJobs1.json' -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headers
```

You might also try the `invoke-restmethod` cmdlet if the uri is a pure REST endpoint.

Finally you might try a variation of this to get the JSON into a local variable with something like

```
$response = iwr ....
$json = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-JSon
```

unless you really are trying to save the content to a file for later use.